# Android - onTouch don't work

Tags: android, ontouch

this is my code :

```
public class ViewSecond extends View implements View.OnTouchListener{

private Context context;
private Rect tailleEcran;
private Vibrator vibrator;

private Paint paint;
private Paint monPerso = new Paint();
private Paint flecheHaut = new Paint();
private Paint flecheBas = new Paint();
private Paint flecheGauche = new Paint();
private Paint flecheDroite = new Paint();

private Bitmap bmp, bmpFlecheHaut, bmpFlecheBas, bmpFlecheGauche, bmpFlecheDroite;

private Carte carteActuelle;

public ViewSecond(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    this.tailleEcran = getWindowSize();

    this.paint = new Paint();
    this.paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    this.paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    // ON S'OCCUPE DU PERSO PRINCIPAL
    monPerso.setColor(Color.RED);
    monPerso.setAntiAlias(false);
    // ON S'OCCUPE DE LA CARTE
    this.carteActuelle = new Carte(1,1,"lol");
    // ON S'OCCUPE DES FLECHES DIRECTIONNEL
    this.flecheHaut   = new Paint();
    this.flecheBas    = new Paint();
    this.flecheGauche = new Paint();
    this.flecheDroite = new Paint();
    bmp             = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.flechehaut);
    bmpFlecheHaut   = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,(int)(tailleEcran.exactCenterX()*2)/8,(int)(tailleEcran.exactCenterY()*2)/8,false);
    bmp             = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.flechebas);
    bmpFlecheBas    = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,(int)(tailleEcran.exactCenterX()*2)/8,(int)(tailleEcran.exactCenterY()*2)/8,false);
    bmp             = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.flechegauche);
    bmpFlecheGauche = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,(int)(tailleEcran.exactCenterX()*2)/8,(int)(tailleEcran.exactCenterY()*2)/8,false);
    bmp             = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.flechedroite);
    bmpFlecheDroite = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,(int)(tailleEcran.exactCenterX()*2)/8,(int)(tailleEcran.exactCenterY()*2)/8,false);

}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();
    if(((x>100) && (x<550)) && ((y>100) && (y<550))){
        this.vibrator.vibrate(500);
    }
    this.invalidate();
    return false;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    this.paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    this.invalidate();
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawCircle(10, 10, 10, monPerso);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmpFlecheHaut,(int)((tailleEcran.exactCenterX()*2)/8)+10,(int)((tailleEcran.exactCenterY()*2)-(((tailleEcran.exactCenterY()*2)/8)*2)-10),null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmpFlecheBas,(int)((tailleEcran.exactCenterX()*2)/8)+10,(int)((tailleEcran.exactCenterY()*2)-(tailleEcran.exactCenterY()*2)/8),null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmpFlecheGauche,0,(int)((tailleEcran.exactCenterY()*2)-(tailleEcran.exactCenterY()*2)/5.5),null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmpFlecheDroite,(int)((tailleEcran.exactCenterX()*2)/4)+20,(int)((tailleEcran.exactCenterY()*2)-(tailleEcran.exactCenterY()*2)/5.5),null);
}

// CETTE FONCTION RENVOIE UN RECTANGE DE LA TAILLE DE L'ECRAN
Rect getWindowSize() {
    Rect r = new Rect();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    display.getRectSize(r);
    return r;
}}
```

I'm trying to detect when a user is touching the screen, but it's not working, i tried to put it (the onTouch method) here and in the activity but nothing doing :/ Any idea ?
Do you see my drawImages ? Finally what i want is to detect the click on this images. Thx :D

Comment: implement onTouchListener for detect touch...

Comment: As a noob, ... sry. But don't work too :/

Comment: if you are extending a View use onTouchEvent,  not onTouch

Answer (score 2):

Hi if you want to override the public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event).
If you want to handle the whole control then return false other wise return true.
In your case you return false, please update it and try return true. for example see below onTouch method of view.

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
    final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            break; 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break; 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            break; 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            break; 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            break; 
    } 
    _root.invalidate();
    return true; 
}}
```

See it return the true. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `onTouchEvent()` instead of simple `onTouch()` and return `true` in it. If you will return `true` it means that you have consumed touch event and you're telling Android that it doesn't need to process event further.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();
    if(((x>100) && (x<550)) && ((y>100) && (y<550))){
        this.vibrator.vibrate(500);
    }
    this.invalidate();
    return true;
}
```